# AsyncTask and Listview in ListViewFragment with pager

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, adapter, pager

I have used AsyncTask and Listview in ListViewFragment with pager
and I have a problem

What I had problem is all contents which got from Json was loaded in same time on fragments
so, sometimes it is disappeared or mixed on fragment's listview.

This is my ViewPagerAdapter in MainActivity

```
private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {


        if (position == 0)
        {
            return ScrollView_mainpage.newInstance(position);
        }
        else if (position == 1)
        {
            return ListViewFragment2.newInstance(position);
        }
        else if(position ==2)
        {
            return ListViewFragment_TIP.newInstance(position);
        }
        else
        {
            return ScrollView_userpage.newInstance(position);
        }

    }

    @Override

    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return " Home";
            case 1:
                return "    YAAK";
            case 2:
                return "      Tip";
            case 3:
                return "         My";
        }

        return "";
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

And this is my firstFragment made by ScrollView

```
public class ScrollView_mainpage extends BaseViewPagerFragment {

private ScrollView mScrollView;
private ScrollViewDelegate mScrollViewDelegate = new ScrollViewDelegate();
private UserSessionManager session;

TextView status;


public static ScrollView_mainpage newInstance(int index) {
    ScrollView_mainpage fragment = new ScrollView_mainpage();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(BUNDLE_FRAGMENT_INDEX, index);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

//on start에서 사용자 pain에 맞는 sql 데이터와 탑 7아이템을 로드 한 뒤
// 두 엑티비티에 뿌리기
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a_main_scroll_view, container, false);

    mScrollView = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
    session = new UserSessionManager(getActivity());
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

    status = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.status);
    status.setText(user.get(UserSessionManager.POST_USER_PAIN) + " 이 걱정이신 " + user.get(UserSessionManager.POST_USERNAME) + "님");

    android.support.v4.view.ViewPager pager = (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.list__top_pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter());
    android.support.v4.view.ViewPager pager2 = (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.list__recommend_pager);
    pager2.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter());

    return view;


}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    int NumberOfPages = 5;

    int[] res = {
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.two,
            R.drawable.three,
            R.drawable.four,
            R.drawable.five };

    int[] backgroundcolor = {
            0xFF101010,
            0xFF202020,
            0xFF303030,
            0xFF404040,
            0xFF505050 };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumberOfPages;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {


        TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textView.setTextSize(30);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(position));

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        imageView.setImageResource(res[position]);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams imageParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(imageParams);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(backgroundcolor[position]);

        layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        layout.addView(textView);
        layout.addView(imageView);

        final int page = position;
        layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            //여기서 세부 아이팀 리스트로 넘어가게끔 설정 해놓기.

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        "Page " + page + " clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }});

        container.addView(layout);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }

}


@Override public boolean isViewBeingDragged(MotionEvent event) {
    return mScrollViewDelegate.isViewBeingDragged(event, mScrollView);
}


public void closeSilently(Closeable c) {
    if (c == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        c.close();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
}
```

And second FragmentPage is this

```
public class ListViewFragment2 extends BaseViewPagerFragment
        implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {

private ListView mListView;
private ListAdapter mAdapter;
private View v;
private AbsListViewDelegate mAbsListViewDelegate = new AbsListViewDelegate();
private TextView category;
private ListView list;
private String[] array={"전체 카테고리","눈","머리","피로","장(유산균)"};

private final String ITEM_ID = "item_id";
private final String ITEM_NAME = "item_name";
private final String ITEM_BRAND = "item_brand";
private final String ITEM_PRICE = "item_price";
private final String ITEM_IMG = "item_img";
private final String ITEM_USAGE = "item_usage";
private final String ITEM_CATEGORY = "item_category";
private final String ITEM_CAPACITY = "item_capacity";
private final String ITEM_INGREDIENT= "item_ingredient";

private final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";

private final String READ_ALL_CONTENTS = "http://cosmetictoworld.com/alcontents.php";
private final String READ_ITEM_CONTETNS = "http://cosmetictoworld.com/temcontents.php";


private ProgressBar pBar;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private JSONArray mComments = null;
public Integer len;
//private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mCommentList;
//private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> AdapList;
private EditText filter;
public static String[] item_nameArray;
public static String[] item_brandArray;
public static String[] item_priceArray;
public static String[] item_capacityArray;
public static String[] item_usageArray;
public static String[] item_ingredientArray;
public static String[] item_imgArray;
public static String[] item_categoryArray;
public static String[] item_idArray;

ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<Item>();
itemListAdapter itemAdapter;

public static ListViewFragment2 newInstance(int index) {
    ListViewFragment2 fragment = new ListViewFragment2();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(BUNDLE_FRAGMENT_INDEX, index);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public ListViewFragment2() {
}
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a_item_list_view, container, false);
    pBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.circularProgressbar);
    new LoadItem().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);
    category = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.category);
    category.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            dlg.setTitle("제품 카테고리");
            dlg.setItems(array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    category.setText(array[which]);
                    if(array[which].equals("전체 카테고리"))
                        itemAdapter.filter("all");
                    else if (array[which].equals("눈"))
                        itemAdapter.filter("eye");
                    else if (array[which].equals("장(유산균)"))
                        itemAdapter.filter("gut");
                    else if (array[which].equals("머리"))
                        itemAdapter.filter("brain");
                    else if (array[which].equals("피로"))
                        itemAdapter.filter("fatigue");
                }
            });
            dlg.show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}
synchronized  public void updateList(){

    list = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
    arrayList.clear();

    for(int i=0; i<item_nameArray.length; i++)
    {
        Item item = new Item(item_nameArray[i],item_brandArray[i],item_priceArray[i],
                item_capacityArray[i],item_usageArray[i],
                item_ingredientArray[i],item_imgArray[i],item_categoryArray[i],
                item_idArray[i]);
        arrayList.add(item);
    }
    itemAdapter = new itemListAdapter(getContext(), arrayList);
    list.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
    list.setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.empty));

    filter = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.filter);
    filter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String text = filter.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            itemAdapter.filter(text);


        }
    });

}
synchronized public void updateJSONdata_item() {

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_ALL_CONTENTS);

    try{

        mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
        len = mComments.length();

        item_nameArray = new String[len];
        item_brandArray = new String[len];
        item_priceArray = new String[len];
        item_capacityArray  = new String[len];
        item_usageArray  = new String[len];
        item_ingredientArray  = new String[len];
        item_imgArray = new String[len];
        item_categoryArray = new String[len];
        item_idArray = new String[len];

        for(int i= 0; i< mComments.length(); i++) {
            final int index = i;
            JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(index);

            item_idArray[index] = c.getString(ITEM_ID);
            item_nameArray[index]=c.getString(ITEM_NAME);
            item_brandArray[index] = c.getString(ITEM_BRAND);
            item_imgArray[index]= c.getString(ITEM_IMG);
            item_priceArray[index]= c.getString(ITEM_PRICE);
            item_usageArray[index]= c.getString(ITEM_USAGE);
            item_ingredientArray[index] = c.getString(ITEM_INGREDIENT);
            item_categoryArray[index]= c.getString(ITEM_CATEGORY);
            item_capacityArray[index]= c.getString(ITEM_CAPACITY);

        }
    }catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private final class LoadItem extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Resources res = getResources();
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.circular);
        pBar.setProgress(25);   // Main Progress
        pBar.setSecondaryProgress(50); // Secondary Progress
        pBar.setMax(100); // Maximum Progress
        pBar.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        updateJSONdata_item();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pBar.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE);
        updateList();



    }
}

private final class itemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Item> Item_list = null;
    private ArrayList<Item> arrayList;

    public itemListAdapter(Context context,List<Item> Item_list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.Item_list = Item_list;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        this.arrayList.addAll(Item_list);
    }
    class ViewHolder {

        public ImageView img;
        public TextView brand;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView capacity;
        public TextView adapter_category;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return Item_list.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Item getItem(int position){
        return Item_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list_item, parent, false);

            holder.img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_img);
            holder.brand = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_brand);
            holder.name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            holder.capacity = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_capacity);
            holder.adapter_category = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_category);
            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.brand.setText(Item_list.get(position).getItemBrand());
        holder.name.setText(Item_list.get(position).getItemName());
        holder.capacity.setText(Item_list.get(position).getItemCapacity());
        String ca = Item_list.get(position).getItemCategory();
        if(ca.equals("fatigue"))
            holder.adapter_category.setText("전신피로");
        else if(ca.equals("gut"))
            holder.adapter_category.setText("장(유산균)");
        else if(ca.equals("eye"))
            holder.adapter_category.setText("눈,시력");
        else
            holder.adapter_category.setText("머리,기억력");

        String url =Item_list.get(position).getItemImg();
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                        //.fit()
                .resizeDimen(R.dimen.list_detail_image_size, R.dimen.list_detail_image_size)
                .centerInside()
                .tag(context)
                .into(holder.img);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,content_detail.class);
                intent.putExtra("item_id", Item_list.get(position).getItemId());
                intent.putExtra("item_name", Item_list.get(position).getItemName());
                intent.putExtra("item_brand", Item_list.get(position).getItemBrand());
                intent.putExtra("item_price", Item_list.get(position).getItemPrice());
                intent.putExtra("item_ingredient", Item_list.get(position).getItemIngredient());
                intent.putExtra("item_usage", Item_list.get(position).getItemUsage());
                intent.putExtra("item_capacity", Item_list.get(position).getItemCapacity());
                intent.putExtra("item_img", Item_list.get(position).getItemImg());
                intent.putExtra("item_category", Item_list.get(position).getItemCategory());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    public void filter(String charText)
    {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        Item_list.clear();

        if(charText.equals("all"))
            Item_list.addAll(arrayList);

        if(charText.length()==0)
        {
            Item_list.addAll(arrayList);
        } else {
            for(Item item : arrayList)
            {
                if(item.getItemName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
                {
                    Item_list.add(item);
                }
                else if(item.getItemCategory().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
                {
                    Item_list.add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
}

@Override public boolean isViewBeingDragged(MotionEvent event) {
    return mAbsListViewDelegate.isViewBeingDragged(event, mListView);
}
}
```

And this is my third fragment

```
public class ListViewFragment_TIP extends BaseViewPagerFragment
        implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {

private ListView mListView;
private ListAdapter mAdapter;
private AbsListViewDelegate mAbsListViewDelegate = new AbsListViewDelegate();

private final String TIP_ID = "tip_id";
private final String TIP_NAMAE="tip_name";
private final String TIP_CONTENT="tip_content";
private final String TIP_IMG="tip_img";

private final String TAG_POSTS="posts";
private final String READ_ALL_TIP = "http://cosmetictoworld.cafe24.com/tip_contents.php";

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private JSONArray mComments = null;
public Integer len;
private EditText filter;
private ListView list;

private ProgressBar pBar;
public static int indexing;
public static String[] tip_idArray;
public static String[] tip_nameArray;
public static String[] tip_contentArray;
public static String[] tip_imgArray;

ArrayList<Tip> arrayList = new ArrayList<Tip>();
tipListAdapter tipAdapter;
TextView button_tip;

public static ListViewFragment_TIP newInstance(int index) {
    ListViewFragment_TIP fragment = new ListViewFragment_TIP();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    indexing=index;
    args.putInt(BUNDLE_FRAGMENT_INDEX, index);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public ListViewFragment_TIP() {
}

@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a_board_list_view, container, false);
    pBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.circularProgressbar);
    button_tip = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.button_tip);
    new LoadTip().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);



    return view;
}



public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}
synchronized  public void updateList(){

    list = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
    arrayList.clear();

    for(int i=0; i<tip_nameArray.length; i++)
    {
        Tip tip = new Tip(tip_idArray[i],tip_nameArray[i],tip_contentArray[i],
                tip_imgArray[i]);
        arrayList.add(tip);
    }
    tipAdapter = new tipListAdapter(getContext(),arrayList);
    list.setAdapter(tipAdapter);
    list.setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.empty));


}
synchronized public void updateJSONdata_tip() {

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_ALL_TIP);

    try{

        mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
        len = mComments.length();

        tip_idArray = new String[len];
        tip_nameArray = new String[len];
        tip_contentArray = new String[len];
        tip_imgArray = new String[len];

        for(int i= 0; i< mComments.length(); i++) {
            final int index = i;
            JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(index);

            tip_idArray[index] = c.getString(TIP_ID);
            tip_nameArray[index] = c.getString(TIP_NAMAE);
            tip_contentArray[index] = c.getString(TIP_CONTENT);
            tip_imgArray[index] = c.getString(TIP_IMG);
        }
    }catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private final class LoadTip extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Resources res = getResources();
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.circular);
        pBar.setProgress(25);   // Main Progress
        pBar.setSecondaryProgress(50); // Secondary Progress
        pBar.setMax(100); // Maximum Progress
        pBar.setProgressDrawable(drawable);


    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        updateJSONdata_tip();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        updateList();

    }
}

private final class tipListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Tip> tip_list = null;
    private ArrayList<Tip> arrayList;

    public tipListAdapter(Context context, List<Tip> tip_list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.tip_list = tip_list;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<Tip>();
        this.arrayList.addAll(tip_list);
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        public ImageView img;
        public TextView name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tip_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Tip getItem(int position) {
        return tip_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tip_list_item, parent, false);

            holder.img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tip_img);
            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tip_name);
            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        String url = tip_list.get(position).getTip_img();
        Log.d("IMG: ",url);
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                        //.fit()
                .resizeDimen(R.dimen.tip_width_image_size, R.dimen.tip_height_size)
                .centerInside()
                .tag(context)
                .into(holder.img);
        holder.name.setText(tip_list.get(position).getTip_name());

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, content_detail.class);
                intent.putExtra("tip_id", tip_list.get(position).getTip_id());
                intent.putExtra("tip_name", tip_list.get(position).getTip_name());
                intent.putExtra("tip_content", tip_list.get(position).getTip_content());
                intent.putExtra("tip_img", tip_list.get(position).getTip_img());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override public boolean isViewBeingDragged(MotionEvent event) {
    return mAbsListViewDelegate.isViewBeingDragged(event, mListView);
}
}
```

How can I avoid datas loaded in sametime?
and 
How can I ship the data in listview on time?

Comment: Try using [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) and also check if you are using ViewPagerAdapter in fragment then you have to pass getSupportChildFragmentManager() to pass in constructor

Answer (score 0):

```
    new LoadItem().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);
```

This line allows your AsyncTasks to be executed parrallely.
If you don't want that replace THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR with SERIAL_EXECUTOR.